# How to get data-X="123" from span

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my item where `ProductCat =10;`

```
<span class='Category' data-cat=" + ProductCat + ">Cat is:" + ProductCat + " </span>
```

Now I need to take this `data-cat=10` in JavaScript. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: `document.querySelector('.Category').getAttribute('data-Cat')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the jquery:

```
var data = $("span.Category").attr("data-Cat");
```

Comment: Just some more useful info - apparently html5 data attributes aren't supposed to have capital letters in them. If the OP changes "data-Cat" to "data-cat", he/she can use `$("span.Category").data("cat");` instead (jQuery won't respond to the capital letter version).

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for suggestion, will be helpful to other. But OP has not define that he/she is using HTML.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.Category').attr('data-Cat') // returns 10
```